# Angular ngPaste not displaying up to date values within my Directive

Tags: angularjs

[Please see relevant jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/528/)

Within my directive whenever I paste an item on the 'searchBar' or text box I am not getting the updated value of the element text.

Here is my directive:

```
app.directive('searchBar', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="searchData" placeholder="Enter a search" id="searchbarid" />',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

             elem.on('paste', function(evt) {
                   alert(evt.target.value);
                });

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Could you please accept if this solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the event inside of a `$timeout` of 0 so that it evaluates in the next `$digest` after angular evaluates all of its watches.

```
elem.on('paste', function(evt) {
    $timeout(function() {
        alert(evt.target.value);
    },0)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/530/

Comment: Is there any other viable options or is this the best way?

Comment: @BDillan after some testing with ngPaste this seems like the most viable way.